# Create array of objects from array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
["7", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "-3"]
```

I want to create an array of objects with the array as follows:

```js
{
  "region": [{
      "label": "",
      "value": "7"
    },
    {
      "label": "",
      "value": "-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say, your array is in the variable `arr`.
You can use `.map()` to create the new structure.

```js
var arr = ["7", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "-3"];

var result = {
  region: arr.map(value => ({
    label: '',
    value
  }))
};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Instead of `item` you could call it `value` and use the key/value shortcut when you return the object like: `arr.map(value => ({ label: '', value }) ) }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array's [map function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The parameter to this function is another function which will receive each items value and key. You can return an object with any structure you want, thus mapping every value to the correct object, e.g.:

```
[1,2,3].map(function(item) {
    return {"label":"", "value":item};
});
```

will return:

```
[
    {"label":"", "value":1},
    {"label":"", "value":2},
    {"label":"", "value":3}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map function:

```
{ 
   region: ["7", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "-3"].map(v => ( 
   {label:"", value:v}))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can create `Converter` class.
- Create a function who maps the array using an instance of Converter.

This way your code can be re-used.

## Look at this code snippet

```js
var data = ["7", "-1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "-3"];

var Converter = function() {
  this.convert = (n) => ({ "label": "", "value": n});
};

var processArray = (array, converter) => { 
  return { region: array.map((n) => converter.convert(n)) };
};

console.log(processArray(data, new Converter()));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```